# Testing Client/Server app in C++

Tags: c++, networking, software-testing, unix

I am currently developing Client/Server app based on **TCP protocol** in C/C++ and want to perform tests of both client and server side. I am using **unix sockets** for development. Are there any MOCK libs or something similar to be used in testing or do I have to make wrappers in order to perform tests? Do these tests have to be **local** or can they be performed on **network**?